# Javascript-Ajax not able to send any data

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am having trouble making this part of code to work, basically i want to call this function which sends a variable to a php page. Ive tested that the variable is there and also tested that my php page is accepting information as it should be , however i cant make this Ajax thing work.

```
function ajaxRequest(myname) {
var AJAX = null; // Initialize the AJAX variable.
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ // Does this browser have an XMLHttpRequest object?
    AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Yes -- initialize it.
} else 
{ // No, try to initialize it IE style
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // Wheee, ActiveX, how do we format c: again?
} // End setup Ajax.

if (AJAX==null) 
{ // If we couldn't initialize Ajax...
    alert("Your browser doesn't support AJAX."); // Sorry msg.
return false // Return false, couldn't set up ajax
}
AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() 
{ // When the browser has the request info..
    if (AJAX.readyState==4 || AJAX.readyState=="complete") 
    { // see if the complete flag is set.
        callback(AJAX.responseText, AJAX.status); // Pass the response to our processing function
    } // End Ajax readystate check.
}

alert("Alert1");
var url='http://localhost/main.php?Name=myname';    
AJAX.open("POST", url, true); // Open the url this object was set-up with.
alert("Alert2");
AJAX.send(); // Send the request.
```

}

This is my php part which should accept the variable

```
<?php
$var=$_GET['Name'];

echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: I'll probably get heat for this, but I like jQuery's ajax function.  Nice and simple.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, and you don't need to worry so much about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay firstly you need to change your request to GET from POST
like

```
AJAX.open("GET", url, true); // Open the url this object was set-up with.
```

and you also need to update this line
from

```
var url='http://localhost/main.php?Name=myname';
```

to

```
var url='http://localhost/main.php?Name='+myname;
```

my full script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxRequest(myname) {
        var AJAX = null; // Initialize the AJAX variable.
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        { // Does this browser have an XMLHttpRequest object?
            AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Yes -- initialize it.
        } else { // No, try to initialize it IE style
            AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // Wheee, ActiveX, how do we format c: again?
        } // End setup Ajax.

        if (AJAX==null) 
        { // If we couldn't initialize Ajax...
            alert("Your browser doesn't support AJAX."); // Sorry msg.
            return false // Return false, couldn't set up ajax
        }

        AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { // When the browser has the request info..
            if (AJAX.readyState==4 || AJAX.readyState=="complete") 
            { // see if the complete flag is set.
                callback(AJAX.responseText, AJAX.status); // Pass the response to our processing function
            } // End Ajax readystate check.
        }

        alert("Alert1");
        var url='http://localhost/main.php?Name='+myname;    
        AJAX.open("GET", url, true); // Open the url this object was set-up with.
        alert("Alert2");
        AJAX.send(); // Send the request.
    }
</script>
```

you might also be missing the callback function so add it so that it looks like this

```
function callback(x, y) {
    alert(x);
}
```

And call your AJAX function by

```
ajaxRequest("ashley");
```

Here is your required main.php code (even though this isn't what you should be using AJAX for

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_GET["Name"])) {
   $_SESSION["Name"] = $_GET["Name"];
}
if(isset($_SESSION["Name"])) {
   echo $_SESSION["Name"];
} else {
   echo "The AJAX has not been run!";
}
?>
```

Comment: like AlexMA i suggest that you should be using jQuery Ajax as it is a lot easy to use if you are used to jQuery programming

Comment: so i changed what you told me nd have an update, with the callback function alert now i am seeing the variable myname however i'm still missing seeing the variable when i go to http://localhost/main.php and still having the undefined index...

Comment: unless you want it `POST` - then you would need to send the params separately

Comment: Because you won't ever visit the page main.php directly that's not the point of Ajax if you want it to work like that make your main.php look like

Comment: Please see my update at the end of my answer, even though this isn't what ajax is used for...

Comment: @ Ashley ... perfect it worked briliantly, the end of this , is that i pass variables from a php script that will be written in mysql, so basically i wont be visiting main.php directly, i am using it to check if the variables are being sent correctly. Now i will build my sql statements and complete the rest. Thanks indeed for those who contributed to my post. !! Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send an ajax request to server 
Either GET or POST

**1. GET Method:**

```
var url='http://localhost/main.php?Name='+myname; // you can add any numner of vars here
AJAX.open("GET", url, true); 
AJAX.send();
```

Code in main.php

```
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        echo $_GET['Name'];
    }
```

**2. POST Method:**

```
AJAX.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
AJAX.send("Name="+myname);
```

Code in main.php

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    echo $_POST['Name'];
}
```

Comment: @Rajan i've tried also what you told me and now i dont get the undefined function, however i still can see the variable when refreshing the main.php file.

Comment: I have givne just a code snippet and not whole function. YOu just need to replace it with respective lines.

Comment: @RajanRawal you miss understand he wants the main.php to remember the value stored after the AJAX is fired, i have updated my answer to use php sessions

Comment: @RajanRawal your help was also great thanks for your help aswell ! will test both solutions .